# why fused location provider not giving locations in huawei phone in offline mode?

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, offline-mode, sleep-mode

Android fused location provider stop updating in sleep mode and also phone in offline mode not getting location.but the same code working perfectly in samsung phone and huawei phone shows these issues.how to solve these issues.

Comment: `FusedLocationProvider` doesn't work in offline mode

Comment: @OussemaAroua is there a source for this information ?